# Laying out floated and cleared page elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I'm having this problem with page layout that I've been battling for too long to continuing looking at sanely. The overall page layout is a standard two-column: a main column with one narrow one on the right (with `float: right`) and the remainder of the page being the main area.

Now, within the main area, I have a piece of content that needs to float along the right edge of the main area - which is fine.  However then I need to put some content below the floating part in the main area, yet not below the big right column - and I just can't figure out how to do it.

Here's the jsfiddle with what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/rx7Pd/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A sketch would probably make your design goal clearer.

Comment: Would it hurt your pride to use a `<table>` ;-)

Comment: @Barry, It would hurt the *entire Internet* to use a table.  Do you want the blue-green part under the pink part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` to the main container.

> **Updated example**: http://jsfiddle.net/TT8QF/

This is a common fix related to clearing floated divs. You can find some info [**here**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) and [**here**](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html).

If you use this fix on the parent element too, you can get rid of the ugly clearing div at the bottom of HTML code. Just see:

> **Updated example**: http://jsfiddle.net/bNS98/

Comment: Yep, looks like what I need.  Do you recon this will work on IE7 (I'm constrained by a government client requirements)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it works on IE6 too. Just try it.

Comment: Hm... I just added `overflow: auto` to the main area - and it added totally redundant scrollbars on that div - what gives?

Comment: It means some elements are greater or outside their container. Try using `overflow: hidden` instead, in fact I always use `hidden`...

Comment: Yes! this was it: I forgot about a hidden div that's shown with JS on certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this? [(online demo)](http://dabblet.com/gist/2702945)

[image]

wrapper for main content and using for it `display: table-cell` is the main idea of this trick:

**html**

```
    /* full html markup is on my demo */
    …
    <div class="right-main">
            right-floating part of main area.
    </div>
    <div id="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget risus libero. Nunc ornare pretium quam, a blandit magna suscipit viverra. Sed eu metus ut justo viverra tempus id in magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean vitae eros nec mauris vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="rest">
        I want this to be below the main
        right column but not below the
        overall right column
    </div>
    …
```

**css**

```
/* full css code is on my demo */
…
#content {
    display: table-cell
}
…
```